# Convert time format mm.ss.dd to seconds in MS Excel

Tags: excel, format

I have an Excel file with times in this format: mm.ss.dd (dd are the numbers behind the comma).

Examples:

```
12.54.88
4.6.21
```

How do I convert this to seconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have your time in the above format in the cell A2 use the formula `LEFT(A2,FIND(".",A2)-1)*60+MID(A2,FIND(".",A2)+1,FIND(".",A2,FIND(".",A2))-1)+MID(A2,FIND(".",A2,4)+1,2)/100`to convert to seconds.

1.2.30 = 1x60+2+3/100 = 62.30 seconds

Am sorry but I am unable to post a screen shot of the working of the formulae but i think it is self explanatory. Formula calculates the position of the first two decimal points to work the calcualtion.